# Angular 2 Function call in *ngFor getting called multiple times

Tags: angular

I am calling a function on a directive to render series data for a chart.

```
import {Directive, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[onCreate]'
})
export class OnCreate implements OnInit{
  @Input() onCreate:Function;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Directive Initialized. The value is: ', this.onCreate);
  }
}
```

The getSeries Data function is getting called endlessly. It should only be getting called 15 times. What am I doing wrong?

Dashboard Component.ts

```
import{ Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {SimpleChartComponent} from "../charts/simpleChart.component";
import {AppleChartComponent} from "../charts/appleChart.component";
import {BarChartComponent} from "../charts/barChart.component";
import {DonutChartComponent} from "../charts/donutChart.component";
import {AlertComponent} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {ModalDemoComponent} from "../modals/modalDemoComponent";
import {NgInitHelperComponent} from "../helpers/nginit.helper.component";
import {ModalDirective} from "ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap";
import {BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {SurveyService} from "../survey/survey.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: '/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.component.html',
  providers: [BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS],
  directives: [SimpleChartComponent, AppleChartComponent, BarChartComponent, DonutChartComponent, AlertComponent, ModalDemoComponent, NgInitHelperComponent, ModalDirective]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  public areas:any;
  public seriesData: any[];

  constructor(public router: Router, public surveyService: SurveyService) {

    this.router = router;
    this.surveyService = surveyService;
    this.areas = this.surveyService.questions;
    this.seriesData = [20,40,60,80,100];

  }

  ngOnInit(){

    console.log('Dashboard Component Init!');


  }

  goToDimension(id){

      this.router.navigate(['/dimensions', id]);

  }


  getSeriesData(i){

    console.log('Getting series data', i);
    return [1,2,3,4,5]//this will eventually return data via id etc.


  }
}
```

Dashboard Component.html

```
<h1>Welcome to the Dashboard! <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" (click)="m.show()"></i></h1>
<hr/>
<!--<div class="row">-->
<!--<div class="col-md-12"><bar-chart selector="chart_dashboard" heading="Dashboard"></bar-chart></div>-->
<!--</div>-->
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let i of areas" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid grey; margin: 30px 0 0 0; padding-bottom: 20px;">

     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5">
       <div [onCreate]="getSeriesData(i.id)"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7">
        <h3>This items title the area.</h3>

        <p>Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. Some paragraph about this item. </p>

        <div class="text-right">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goToDimension(i.id)">Learn More!</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<modal-demo #m="child"></modal-demo>
```

See image, Directive fires 15 times as intended, but the function call is infinite.

[image: Directive 15 times. GOOD]

[image: Inifinite Loop BAD :(]

Comment: can you provide your 'apple-chart' component's code? and why are you using `selector="{{i.category}}" heading="{{i.category}}"` instead of usual A2 approach `[selector]="i.category" [heading]="i.category"`?

Comment: Oleg, because I am only passing strings.

Comment: ok, so what about appleChart code? or better - to provide Plunkr

Comment: it has been added.

Comment: Angular will call that function every time the model changes, because it has no idea if the model change has an impact on what is computed and returned by the function. That's expected and normal. If you don't want that, then store the data in a field, and recompute it when needed, instead of computing the data on-demand.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you provide a code change or example?

Comment: Your current getSeriesDate() method doesn't do anything, so what could I change?

Comment: And also for your case, after changing from Function to a simple Property - implements OnPush detection strategy for your AppleChart component. Just add it to imports:

`import {..., ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';`

and add to @Component decorator this:

`@Component({
      ...,
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })`

Comment: @JBNizet it's surely does do something. Did you read my post? It fires off the console.log infinite times.

Comment: And that's the desired behavior of a method called `getSeriesData()` and taking an id as argument? log a message and returning false? If that's the desired behavior, you can't change it to a field, because accessing a field won't log anything. If the desired behavior is to get false, you can change `[seriesdata]="getSeriesData(i.id)"` to `[seriesdata]="false"`. If the desired behavior is something completely different, then I can't guess what it is, and you can consider your method as doing, basically, nothing. At least nothing useful or desired.

Comment: @JBNizet  The desired behavior is to return an array each time [seriesdata]="getSeriesData(i.id)" gets called. Right now I am simply trying to  return [1,2,3,4,5] which will then pass into the apple chart component via $Input(). I noticed the function was getting called infinitely in the for loop. Thats why I put the console.log in there. The problem I am trying to solve is the infinite looping, once thats resolve, then I can worry about whats getting passed the the chart component.

Comment: My answer would then be: don't create a new array and return it every time. Just access the same array, always, from your template: [seriesdata]="seriesData".

Comment: @JBNizet each array will ultimately different because in the function call I will be defining a method which will call a service and  return the appropriate data based on the ID. HOW DO I GET RID OF THE LOOP. Thats the question here. NEXT?

Comment: In ngOnInit, get the serieData for each of the areas, store them into the area (or in a separate object, or wherever you want), and in your template, use `[seriesdata]="i.serieData"` (or `[seriesdata]="separateObject[i.id]"`). The point being: don't compute the data on demand and return a new array every time. Compute them once.

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated my question to focus on the looping issue. Please revise or read one more time.

Comment: Just provided console with update

Comment: Why does computing on demand cause the loop, because of ngModel watchers?

Comment: @JBNizet I did what you requested an it now works.

Answer (score 1):

So solve the issue I am setting the data on init.
I then bing to the data in the loop via seriesData[i.id]

```
<div [seriesData]="seriesData[i.id]"></div>
```

Thanks.